# Angularjs ng-bind-html-unsafe replacement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, ng-bind-html

I used to be able to use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` to output unsanitized code (because sanitization happens serverside).

But now that option is gone? I know I can use `$sce.trustAsHtml` but adding that to the JavaScript all over the place is a huge pain when unsafe was so easy to use.

How do I get unsafe back?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, it's quite simple to just create your own directive, here is an example.

**Directive**:

```
app.directive('bindHtmlUnsafe', function( $compile ) {
    return function( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {

        var compile = function( newHTML ) { // Create re-useable compile function
            newHTML = $compile(newHTML)($scope); // Compile html
            $element.html('').append(newHTML); // Clear and append it
        };

        var htmlName = $attrs.bindHtmlUnsafe; // Get the name of the variable 
                                              // Where the HTML is stored

        $scope.$watch(htmlName, function( newHTML ) { // Watch for changes to 
                                                      // the HTML
            if(!newHTML) return;
            compile(newHTML);   // Compile it
        });

    };
});
```

**Usage**:

```
<div bind-html-unsafe="testHTML"></div>
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cC5VZ/2**

Comment: Thanks! Why do you clear and append it instead of just setting it with `.html()`?

Comment: Because if you use `html();` it end's up like this `[object HTMLHeadingElement]` and I also prefer to append anyway

Comment: it doesn't for me. Appending it is slower AFAIK, I changed it to just use html()

Comment: Seems kinda ridiculous they would remove useful functionality and force people to write their own directives for it.

Comment: @CorayThan That's angular for you.

Comment: @CorayThan Don't be hating. They improved security and made it harder for ignorant users to unknowingly compromise their apps. [see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#Example), all you need to do is use `$sce.trustAsHtml(...)` to explicitly trusted html.

Answer (score 23):

Simpler again.

```
App.filter('unsafe', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (val) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
    };
}]);
```

Usage:

`<any ng-bind-html="content | unsafe"></any>`

For more on html binding check the docs [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Just a warning: make sure you actually trust the html, or you could be opening a hole in your sites security.

Comment: Worked fine with ng-bind-html but *not* with `<p>{{ … }}</p>` for me.

Comment: Thanks @HenrikN you are correct. `{{ ... }}` will only print out the text of the content. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @J-Dizzle That is pretty similar. I guess he got their first, though it is a pretty common and well known pattern. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: So simple.  So elegant.  So beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest way, without $sce:**

```
module.directive('html', function() {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        var update = function() {
            element.html(scope.html);
        }

        attrs.$observe('html', function(value) {
            update();
        });
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        scope:  {
            html:   '='
        }
    };
});
```

**How to use:**

```
<div html="angular.variable"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend checking out this *SIMPLE* JSFiddle example.
Was a lifesaver:

http://jsfiddle.net/cC5VZ/2/

```
<div ng-app="ngBindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ngBindHtmlCtrl">
   <p ng-bind-html="myHTML" compile-template></p>
  </div>
</div>



var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('testApp', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.testHTML = '<h1> Welcome :) </h1>';
});

app.directive('bindHtmlUnsafe', function( $parse, $compile ) {
    return function( $scope, $element, $attrs ) {
        var compile = function( newHTML ) {
            newHTML = $compile(newHTML)($scope);
            $element.html('').append(newHTML);        
        };

        var htmlName = $attrs.bindHtmlUnsafe;

        $scope.$watch(htmlName, function( newHTML ) {
            if(!newHTML) return;
            compile(newHTML);
        });

    };
});
```