# Which expression wouldn't pass $sce.trustAsHtml sanitize?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

Suppose I have -

```
$scope.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml; 

<p ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(expression)"></p>
```

What does the `trustAsHtml` could check such that its `expression` wouldn't displayed as trust HTML ?

Please provide me some examples .

Comment: Show your controller code?

Comment: It doesn't matter , I just trying to understand the `trustAsHtml` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

**Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE)** is a mode in which AngularJS requires bindings in certain contexts to result in a value that is marked as safe to use for that context. One example of such a context is binding arbitrary html controlled by the user via ng-bind-html. We refer to these contexts as privileged or SCE contexts.

> Note : If you use normal html using directly bind in html using
>   ng-bind-html. if you have some special characters found in the html
>   means i am suggested use $sce.trustAsHtml() and bind it

**For example**

That should be:

```
<div ng-bind-html="trustedHtml"></div>
```

plus in your controller:

```
$scope.html = '<span onmouseover="this.textContent=&quot;Explicitly trusted HTML bypasses sanitization.&quot;">Hover over this text.</span>';
$scope.trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.html);
```

Comment: But as understood , the `trustedHtml ` also check whether  the passed context is safe , so which expression could be unsafe here ?

Comment: It have option for that `ng-bind-html-unsafe`

Comment: You indicated that you're using Angular 1.2.0... as one of the other comments indicated, ng-bind-html-unsafe has been deprecated.

Comment: Always use ng-bind-html it was safe

Comment: But you want use directive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926306/angularjs-ng-bind-html-unsafe-replacement like this

Comment: You miss the point of my question , I ask - which `expression` content will be blocked by the directives you mentioned ?