# Angular 2 equivalent of ng-bind-html, $sce.trustAsHTML(), and $compile?

Tags: innerhtml, angular

In Angular 1.x, we could insert HTML in real-time by using the HTML tag `ng-bind-html`, combined with the JavaScript call `$sce.trustAsHTML()`. This got us 80% of th way there, but wouldn't work when Angular tags were used, such as if you inserted HTML that used `ng-repeat` or custom directives.

To get that to work, we could use a [custom directive that called $compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926306/angularjs-ng-bind-html-unsafe-replacement).

What is the equivalent for all of this in Angular 2? We can bind using `[inner-html]` but this only works for very simple HTML tags such as `<b>`. It doesn't transform custom angular 2 directives into functioning HTML elements. (Much like Angular 1.x without the `$compile` step.) What is the equivalent of `$compile` for Angular 2?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Angular2 you should use [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) to insert some "compiled content" on the page. So for example if you want to compile next html:

```html
<div>
    <p>Common HTML tag</p>
    <angular2-component>Some angular2 component</angular2-component>
</div>
```

then you need to create component with this html as a template (let's call it `CompiledComponent`) and use `DynamicComponentLoader` to insert this component on the page.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'compiled-component'
})
@View({
  directives: [Angular2Component],
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Common HTML tag</p>
      <angular2-component>Angular 2 component</angular2-component>
    </div>
  `
})
class CompiledComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <h2>Before container</h2>
    <div #container></div>
    <h2>After conainer</h2>
  `
})
class App {
  constructor(loader: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    loader.loadIntoLocation(CompiledComponent, elementRef, 'container');
  }
}
```

Check out [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SvhzsaAx7kvH245wDfmb?p=preview)

**UPD** You can create component dynamically right before the `loader.loadIntoLocation()` call:

```js
// ... annotations
class App {
  constructor(loader: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    // template generation
    const generatedTemplate = `<b>${Math.random()}</b>`;

    @Component({ selector: 'compiled-component' })
    @View({ template: generatedTemplate })
    class CompiledComponent {};

    loader.loadIntoLocation(CompiledComponent, elementRef, 'container');
  }
}
```

I personally don't like it, it's look like a dirty hack to me. But here is [the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YYyMwVAakktn2FoVhKN4?p=preview)

**PS** Beware that at this moment angular2 is under active development. So situation can be changed at any time.

Comment: Is it possible to change the template's HTML at run-time using JavaScript? The HTML isn't known in advance for me to be able to type it into the template... it is computed on the fly.

Comment: AFAIK You can't change properties of component decorators. And this is not a good idea.

Comment: So, imaging the scenario where you have json coming back from the server over time. You want to show a diff between two of these json responses with some html formatting injected for green or red based on if a line was added or removed.  This is not a supported use case in Angular2 as far as you know since the template is dynamic?

Comment: For my use-case I was able to just add a style tag into the returned html. It is not pretty but works for now.

Comment: @JimTheDev I updated the example, adding dynamic creation of component (dirty hack for me). What about your question with diffs, I don't see something special in this case. You just need to create `JsonDiff` component (`<json-diff json1="firstJson" json2="secondJson"/>`) which must be responsible for rendering the diff between two jsons. Maybe you'll need to create some auxiliary components for recursion handling, but not something really special.

Comment: @vern-jensen I've updated question with dynamic component creation.

Comment: Very interesting that that dynamic component bit works. I'll have to look into that further. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone provide an example of data binding between parent component and child inserted using DynamicComponentLoader? There are a lot of examples  on how to insert child, but no examples on how to bind some data to it.

Comment: @AlexBarannikov -`DynamicComponentLoader` accepts a `providers` argument for this purpose.

Comment: @drewmoore, I thought that providers is for DI that can provide some services into component's constructor. But what I need is databinding to properties, like I will appreciate if you point me to some example with databinding, especially with "two-way"

Comment: (wasted 2 hour) , The solution is very simple, Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding?rq=1

Comment: This answer should be scrapped, it is obsolete, doesn't work anymore, and is a bad approach all the way. This is the way to go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

DynamicComponentLoader is deprecated, you can use ComponentResolver instead

You could use this directive, add pipes if you need additional data manipulation. It also allows for lazy loading, you don't need it in your case, but it's worth mentioning.

Directive(I found this code and made some changes, you can do that too to make it fit your taste or use it as is):

```
import { Component, Directive, ComponentFactory, ComponentMetadata, ComponentResolver, Input, ReflectiveInjector, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
declare var $:any;

export function createComponentFactory(resolver: ComponentResolver, metadata: ComponentMetadata): Promise<ComponentFactory<any>> {
    const cmpClass = class DynamicComponent {};
    const decoratedCmp = Component(metadata)(cmpClass);
    return resolver.resolveComponent(decoratedCmp);
}

@Directive({
    selector: 'dynamic-html-outlet',
})
export class DynamicHTMLOutlet {
  @Input() htmlPath: string;
  @Input() cssPath: string;

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentResolver) {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (!this.htmlPath) return;
    $('dynamic-html') && $('dynamic-html').remove();
    const metadata = new ComponentMetadata({
        selector: 'dynamic-html',
        templateUrl: this.htmlPath +'.html',
        styleUrls:  [this.cssPath]
    });
    createComponentFactory(this.resolver, metadata)
      .then(factory => {
        const injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([], this.vcRef.parentInjector);
        this.vcRef.createComponent(factory, 0, injector, []);
      });
  }
}
```

Example how to use it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicHTMLOutlet } from './../../directives/dynamic-html-outlet/dynamicHtmlOutlet.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-home',
  templateUrl: './app/content/home/home.component.html',
  directives: [DynamicHTMLOutlet]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit{
    html: string;
    css: string;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(){
    this.html = './app/content/home/home.someTemplate.html';
    this.css = './app/content/home/home.component.css';
    }

  }
```

home.component.html:

```
<dynamic-html-outlet [htmlPath]="html" [cssPath]="css"></dynamic-html-outlet>
```

Comment: Hi... Above solution is giving error as below,



Typescript Error
Module '"D:/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ComponentResolver'.

Typescript Error
Module '"D:/app/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ComponentMetadata'.

Answer (score 4):

After reading a lot, and being close of opening a new topic I decided to answer here just to try to help to others. As I've seen there are several changes with the latest version of Angular 2. (Currently Beta9)

I'll try to share my code in order to avoid the same frustration I had...

**First, in our index.html**

As usual, we should have something like this:

```
<html>
 ****
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**AppComponent (using innerHTML)**

With this property you will be able to render the basic HTML, but you won't be able to do something similar to Angular 1.x as $compile through a scope:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
                <h1>Hello my Interpolated: {{title}}!</h1>
                <h1 [textContent]="'Hello my Property bound: '+title+'!'"></h1>
                <div [innerHTML]="htmlExample"></div>
             `,
})

export class AppComponent {
    public title = 'Angular 2 app';
    public htmlExample = '  <div>' +
                                '<span [textContent]="\'Hello my Property bound: \'+title"></span>' +
                                '<span>Hello my Interpolated: {{title}}</span>' +
                            '</div>'
}
```

This will render the following:

> Hello my Interpolated: Angular 2 app!
>
> Hello my Property bound: Angular 2 app!
>
> Hello my Interpolated: {{title}}

**AppComponent Using [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html)**

There is a little bug with the docs, documented in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35508458/dynamiccomponentloader-in-angular2-beta-no-component-directive-at-element). So if we have in mind that, my code should look now like this:

```
import {DynamicComponentLoader, Injector, Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    template: `
        <div>
            <h2 [textContent]="'Hello my Property bound: '+title"></h2>
            <h2>Hello my Interpolated: {{title}}</h2>
        </div>
    `
})
class ChildComponent {
     title = 'ChildComponent title';
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
                <h1>Hello my Interpolated: {{title}}!</h1>
                <h1 [textContent]="'Hello my Property bound: '+title+'!'"></h1>
                <div #child></div>
                <h1>End of parent: {{endTitle}}</h1>
             `,
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    public title = 'Angular 2 app';
    public endTitle= 'Bye bye!';

    constructor(private dynamicComponentLoader:DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
//        dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, elementRef, 'child');
    }

    ngOnInit():any {
        this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, this.elementRef, 'child');
    }
}
```

This will render the following:

> Hello my Interpolated: Angular 2 app!
>
> Hello my Property bound: Angular 2 app!
>
> Hello my Property bound: ChildComponent title
>
> Hello my Interpolated: ChildComponent title
>
> End of parent: Bye bye!

Answer (score 4):

I think all you have to do is set the element you want to have compiled html with the [innerHTML]="yourcomponentscopevar"

Comment: Could you elaborate on this solution?

Comment: this.yourcomponentscopevar = '<b>text in bold</b>';

Comment: Do you have any advise on this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68637985/issue-with-ng-html-compile-displaying-ui-grid-twice-while-rendering-saved-html-f

Answer (score 0):

Angular provided `DynamicComponentLoader` class for loading html dynamically. `DynamicComponentLoader` have methods for inserting components. `loadIntoLocation` is one of them for inserting component.

**paper.component.ts**

```
import {Component,DynamicComponentLoader,ElementRef,Inject,OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import { BulletinComponent } from './bulletin.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'paper',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/paper.html'

    }
})
export class PaperComponent {
    constructor(private dynamicComponentLoader:DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef) {

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.dynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation(BulletinComponent, this.elementRef,'child');

    }
}
```

**bulletin.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'bulletin',
    templateUrl: 'app/views/bulletin.html'
    }
})
export class BulletinComponent {}
```

**paper.html**

```
<div>
    <div #child></div>
</div>
```

Few things you need to take care of :

- Don't call `loadIntoLocation` inside the constructor of class . Component view is not yet created when component constructor is called. You will get error -

> Error during instantiation of AppComponent!. There is no component
>   directive at element [object Object]

- Put anchorName #child in html otherwise you will get error.

> Could not find variable child

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dynamic-template

After a long research, only this thing helped me. The rest of the solutions seems to be outdated.