# How to Unit Test a Directive In Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular, angular2-directives

**Problem:** I would like to be able to *unit test a directive in Angular 2 to make sure that it properly compiles.*

In Angular 1, it was possible to use`$compile(angular.element(myElement)` service and call `$scope.$digest()` after that. I specifically want to be able to do this in unit tests so I could test that when Angular ends up running across `<div my-attr-directive/>` in the code that `my-attr-directive` compiles.

**Constraints:**

- **Angular 2 using JAVASCRIPT**. All sources somewhat related seem to require TS. [Perhaps this resource truly does solve the problem](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-unit-testing-with-jasmine-defe20421584#.m2kperx0x) and my understanding of TS is just that weak
- **Unit Test in Jasmine**
- Must be not be so hacky that my unit tests will eventually break. See [a related SO post on compiling HTML manually in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807798/how-to-compile-html-in-angular-2)

Comment: You use `TestComponentBuilder` as shown in the lined SO question/answer. Create a test component where the directive is used in the template and then get a reference to the directive from the created test component instance.

Comment: Thanks for answering both. Just realized that you answered that question previously! I thought there was a comment on that answer regarding removing support for `TestComponentBuilder` when it got moved to a different package, but I think I'm blurring SO posts in my mind. Thanks. I'll close this one out?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

### Testing compiled directive using TestBed

Let's say you have a following directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]',
})
class MyDirective {
  public directiveProperty = 'hi!';
}
```

What you have to do, is to create a component that uses the directive (it can be just for testing purpose):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-test-component',
  template: ''
})
class TestComponent {}
```

Now you need to create a module that has them declared:

```
describe('App', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestComponent,
        MyDirective
      ]
    });
  });

  // ...

});
```

You can add the template (that contains directive) to the component, but it can be handled dynamically by overwriting the template in test:

```
it('should be able to test directive', async(() => {
  TestBed.overrideComponent(TestComponent, {
    set: {
      template: '<div my-directive></div>'
    }
  });

  // ...      

}));
```

Now you can try to compile the component, and query it using `By.directive`. At the very end, there is a possibility to get a directive instance using the `injector`:

```
TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  const directiveEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MyDirective));
  expect(directiveEl).not.toBeNull();

  const directiveInstance = directiveEl.injector.get(MyDirective);
  expect(directiveInstance.directiveProperty).toBe('hi!');
});
```

### # Old answer:

To test a directive you need to create a fake component with it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-cmp',
  directives: [MyAttrDirective],
  template: ''
})
class TestComponent {}
```

You can add the template in the component itself but it can be handled dynamically by overwriting the template in test:

```
it('Should setup with conversation', inject([TestComponentBuilder], (testComponentBuilder: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    return testComponentBuilder
      .overrideTemplate(TestComponent, `<div my-attr-directive></div>`)
      .createAsync(TestComponent)
      .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        const directiveEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('[my-attr-directive]'));
        expect(directiveEl.nativeElement).toBeDefined();
      });
  }));
```

Note that you're able to test what directive renders but I couldn't find the way to test a directive in a way components are (there is no TestComponentBuilder for directives).

Comment: I am getting error : No provider for DirectiveResolver what could be the possible cause?

Comment: To make use of *By* you will need to `import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

Comment: what about the difective has  @input member?, 
I am interested to add unit test to this control: https://github.com/czeckd/angular-dual-listbox.. but i don't know how to start.

Comment: @Wojchieh - `const directiveEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MyDirective));` is really helpful. Great answer

Comment: Accessing directive instance though injector: Brilliant :) I'll remember that. Thanks

Comment: Instead of accessing the Directive instance through injector why not just define a property on the TestComponent as follows:
`@ViewChild(MyDirective) directiveInstance: MyDirective`
and then use it in your test case like this    
`expect(fixture.componentInstance.directiveInstance.directiveProperty).toBe('hi!');`

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to find a good example, a good person on angular gitter channel pointed me to look at the Angular Material Design 2 repository for examples. You can find a Directive test example [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/tooltip/tooltip.spec.ts). This is the test file for the tooltip directive of Material Design 2. It looks like you have to test it as part of a component.

Comment: Cool resource! Thanks for sharing. It doesn't meet my requirements of the question of being a JS file.

Comment: It is difficult to find any resources in pure JS. One idea would be to get the material design repo, compile it and have a look at the .js file that it produces. I will be surprised by how clean is the JavaScript code produced by the Typescript compiler

Comment: It is difficult to find any resources in pure JS at the moment. One idea would be to get the material design repo, compile it and have a look at the .js file that it produces. You will be surprised by how clean is the JavaScript code produced by the Typescript compiler

Comment: That's a good example to follow. It looks like the repo has been re-organized. The tooltip spec is now [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/tooltip/tooltip.spec.ts)

Comment: The link is broken.