# DynamicComponentLoader in Angular2 beta: "no component directive at element"

Tags: angular

I can't get angular's DynamicComponentLoader to work in beta.6

I've taken the example code for dynamic component loading [from their docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html#!#sts=loadIntoLocation(type:%20Type,%20hostLocation:%20ElementRef,%20anchorName:%20string,%20providers%3F:%20ResolvedProvider%5B%5D,%20projectableNodes%3F:%20any%5B%5D%5B%5D)%20:%20Promise%3CComponentRef%3E), and added it to their working starter code in [plnkr, see here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N7U5NkgvjRPPhHT2lGmF?p=preview).

Here's the code:

```
import {Component, DynamicComponentLoader, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: 'Child'
})
class ChildComponent {
}


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1><div #child></div>'
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, elementRef: ElementRef) {
    dcl.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, elementRef, 'child');
  }
}
```

And here is the stacktrace, which says: "There is no component directive at element":

```
EXCEPTION: Error during instantiation of AppComponent!.BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
angular2.dev.js:23083 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: There is no component directive at element [object Object]BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
angular2.dev.js:23083 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
angular2.dev.js:23083 Error: There is no component directive at element [object Object]
    at new BaseException (angular2.dev.js:7351)
    at AppViewManager_.getNamedElementInComponentView (angular2.dev.js:6441)
    at DynamicComponentLoader_.loadIntoLocation (angular2.dev.js:12375)
    at new AppComponent (run.plnkr.co/mk31ybnwEtsiX31r/app/app.component.ts!transpiled:33)
    at angular2.dev.js:1420
    at Injector._instantiate (angular2.dev.js:11459)
    at Injector._instantiateProvider (angular2.dev.js:11395)
    at Injector._new (angular2.dev.js:11385)
    at InjectorInlineStrategy.instantiateProvider (angular2.dev.js:11149)
    at ElementDirectiveInlineStrategy.init (angular2.dev.js:9081)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
angular2.dev.js:23083 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
angular2.dev.js:23083 _ContextcomponentElement: nullelement: my-appinjector: Injector__proto__: _ContextBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:23083
angular2-polyfills.js:1152 DEPRECATION WARNING: 'dequeueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use removeTask/removeRepeatingTask/removeMicroTask
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Update 4 (and final)

**DynamicComponentLoader** is being deprecated (see [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/5297c9d9ccc6f8831d1656915e3d78e767022517)). Now the correct way is to use `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentResolver` (see update 3 below) for an example in the constructor.

---

---

In beta.1 there was a breaking change. You can't access anymore the view in the constructor. So you can move that example to ngOnInit() and it will work.

Quoting from the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-3)

> Component view is not yet created when component constructor is called. -> use onInit lifecycle callback to access the view of a component

```js
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, private elementRef: ElementRef) {
   
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(ChildComponent, this.elementRef, 'child');
  }
}
```

Check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rPyNrvaycuANKbn5nMxv?p=preview) with your example working.

## Update

Just for your information I've sent a PR (see [#7186](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7186)) to fix the examples in the source code. So hopefully they will review it and it will pass.

## Update 2

Since beta.16 `loadIntoLocation` was removed and the error is no longer reproducible. `loadNextToLocation` now takes a `ViewContainerRef`. I opened a new PR (see [#8241](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8241)) to add a new example of it, everything else is already covered by the original PR.

**Code example (update 3)**

As mentioned above now there's no `loadIntoLocation` but the same behavior is achieved by using `ViewContainerRef` and `ComponentResolver`.

```js
constructor(cmpResolver: ComponentResolver, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {

  cmpResolver.resolveComponent(MyComponent)
    .then((factory: ComponentFactory) => {
        viewContainer.createComponent(factory, 0, viewContainer.injector)
    });
}
```

Reference

- [`ViewContainerRef#createComponent`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewContainerRef-class.html)
- [`ComponentResolver#resolveComponent`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentResolver-class.html)

Regarding `loadNextToLocation`, there are two ways, both use `ViewContainerRef`.

- Using `ViewContainerRef` from the element itself

```js
constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {
    dcl.loadNextToLocation(MyComponent, viewContainer).then(ref => {});
}
```

- Using some element on the view

```js
// Assume the next view
template : '<div #container></div>';

class MyClass {
   @ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef}) container : ViewContainerRef;
    
   constructor(private dcl: DynamicComponentLoader) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dcl.loadNextToLocation(MyDynamicCmp, this.container).then(ref => {});
   }
}
```

A [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/lxqPxFCa7gNlsRZfxI8E?p=info) with the example above.

Comment: Would you mind updating your example code to reflect the API change?