# HTML tags are not getting resolved in Ionic 2 App when used through typescript variable

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 RC.0. In the html file

```
  <ion-item no-lines>
    <ion-label style="text-align:justify">{{labelAndAlerts.LBL_WCACK_STATEMENT}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

where the value of labelAndAlerts.LBL_WCACK_STATEMENT is something like:

```
Please select the following <b>Some Bold Value</b> and <b>Some Another Bold Value</b>.
```

The problem is when my page is loading the bold tags are printing as it is instead of bold values. How cam I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 equivalent of ng-bind-html, $sce.trustAsHTML(), and $compile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340641/angular-2-equivalent-of-ng-bind-html-sce-trustashtml-and-compile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this

```
<ion-label style="text-align:justify">
  <div [outerHTML]="labelAndAlerts.LBL_WCACK_STATEMENT"></div>
</ion-label>
```

[outerHTML documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)