# How to turn text into html object in Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, text, ionic-framework

This is my first question here and I'm only asking because I really couldn't find an answer anywhere - or couldn't figure out how to make it work for me at least (I'm a huge noob when it comes to HTML and Ionic).

Here's the thing:
I'm using Ionic and I want to make a text variable work as an HTML object. Instead, it ends up being merely displayed as text (with tags and everything) on the page.

**TypeScript** (dice.ts)

```
export class Dice {
```

...

```
dice = 4;
result = 0;
teste = "<h2>Teste</h2>";
```

...

**HTML** (dice.html)

```
<ion-content padding>

<h1> TITULO </h1>
{{teste}}
```

...

```
</ion-content>
```

**Outcome**

```
TITULO
<h2>Teste</h2>
```

In other words, it did not create a "header2", but just showed the original string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ogari,
Please try

```
<div [innerHTML]={{teste}}></div>
```

You will find more about this [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! And sorry it took me so long for the feedback.
I had already solved my issue with a workaround using ngContainer and ngFor, but now it's much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <h1> TITULO </h1>
  <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="teste"></div>
</ion-content>
```

also, some more reference: [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/angularjs-insert-html-into-view)

Comment: I did try this before and now, once again, tried it with your code (copy-pasted it) and the text simply disappeared. Instead of displaying the header correctly, it showed absolutely nothing. It simply printed "TITULO" (as a "header1") and nothing else. Thank you very much, anyway!

Comment: You are using angular2, check this one instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/32341540/3760661