# Angular2 : Inject HTML from an array and render the view

Tags: angularjs, object, render, inject

I building a basic drag and drop that has various prepared HTML that you can drag and drop into the page.

I got a object with the list of HTML that you can drag

```
element=[
 text: {html: '<p> asdasdasdas</p>'},
 list: {html: '<ul><li></li></ul>'};
 img: {html: '<img src="placeholder.jpg"/>'}
]
```

How to inject the html into the page?

Or should I be creating the HTML snippets as component and than having  a referenced in the elements object to the component selector and injecting the angular selector and rendering the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-bind-html to bind html

```
<div ng-bind-html="element.text.html"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="element.list.html"></div>
<div ng-bind-html="element.img.html"></div>
```

Notice: You have to include ngSanitize module on your app in order to use ng-bind-html

Comment: what happens if I got angular class inside that HTML and I bind the HTML would it bind the event listeners also?

Comment: You have to inject $sce to your controller and then set your html with trustAsHtml function. Example: `$scope.htmlText = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.element.text.html)`

Comment: $scope is angular 1, I am talking about angular 2 buddy :)

Comment: Okay take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340641/angular-2-equivalent-of-ng-bind-html-sce-trustashtml-and-compile